# Transistioning between html videos

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a html5 webapp that is going to be displayed on tablet devices.  In this webapp there is a video that is playing.  The users are able to select different areas in the video to play a different video.  This is done by overlaying an invisible image with area tags that call up js to switch the video.  What I am wondering is if there is a way to load these videos quicker and possibly add some sort of video transition overtop to make it look more professional. Here is my current app:

```
<!doctype html /> 
<html> 
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay>
            <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

        <div style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 8px; z-index: 1;">
            <img src="" width="320" height="240" usemap="#grid">
            <map name="grid">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,160,240" href="javascript:loadLeftVideo()" alt="Left">
                <area shape="rect" coords="161,0,320,240" href="javascript:loadRightVideo()" alt="Right">
            </map>
       </div>
    </div>

<script>
  function loadLeftVideo() {
    document.querySelector("#video > source").src = "left.mp4"
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }

  function loadRightVideo() {
    document.querySelector("#video > source").src = "right.mp4"
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }
</script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326604/1865613). Based on Googles [Media Source API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API).